# Query SPARQL between two RDF file

Tags: java, eclipse, sparql, jena

I have two rdf files, the first is a data stream and the second a knowledge base. I wish through this query will be able to do a join between the two files so that according to idSensore value of the stream file to find the information (tipologia and valore) of the same idSensore on knowledgebase.

This is my code:

```
String queryBody = "REGISTER QUERY noreasoning AS "
        + "PREFIX :<http://www.dati.lombardia.it/resource/_647i-nhxk/> "
        + "PREFIX ds:<http://www.dati.lombardia.it/resource/nf78-nj6b/> "

        + "SELECT ?idSensore ?tipologia ?valore "

        + "FROM STREAM <http://streamreasoning.org/streams/sensors> [RANGE 1s STEP 1s] "
        + "FROM <http://streamreasoning.org/roomConnection> "                   

        + "WHERE { "

        + "??????????????"
        + "} ";
```

This is stream RDF file :

```xml
<rdf:Description rdf:about="http://www.dati.lombardia.it/resource/_647i-nhxk/18899588">
    <socrata:rowID>18899588</socrata:rowID>
    <rdfs:member rdf:resource="http://www.dati.lombardia.it/resource/_647i-nhxk"/>
    <ds:idsensore>2447</ds:idsensore>
    <ds:data>2016-05-01T09:10:00</ds:data>
    <ds:valore>6</ds:valore>
    <ds:stato>VA</ds:stato></rdf:Description>
```

This is knowledgebase RDF file :

```xml
<rdf:Description rdf:about="http://www.dati.lombardia.it/resource/nf78-nj6b/1">
    <socrata:rowID>1</socrata:rowID>
    <rdfs:member rdf:resource="http://www.dati.lombardia.it/resource/nf78-nj6b"/>
    <ds:idsensore>2001</ds:idsensore>
    <ds:tipologia>Temperatura</ds:tipologia>
    <ds:unit_dimisura>C</ds:unit_dimisura>
    <ds:idstazione>100</ds:idstazione>
    <ds:nomestazione>Milano - Lambrate</ds:nomestazione>
    <ds:quota>120</ds:quota>
    <ds:provincia>MI</ds:provincia>
    <ds:nomecomune>Milano</ds:nomecomune>
    <ds:indirizzo>parco Lambro - acquedotto</ds:indirizzo>
    <ds:cgb_nord>5038191</ds:cgb_nord>
    <ds:cgb_est>1520147</ds:cgb_est>
    <ds:lng>9.25751572</ds:lng>
    <ds:lat>45.49678183</ds:lat>
    <ds:location><geo:SpatialThing>
        <geo:lat>45.49678183</geo:lat>
        <geo:long>9.25751572</geo:long></geo:SpatialThing></ds:location></rdf:Description>
```

Help me for a query please

Comment: If you want to JOIN on IDs, why not just use two triple patterns with a common object that denotes the ID but different subjects and objects.

Comment: I can't because in datastream the IDs are URI and in KnowledgeBase data the IDs are litteral

Comment: In your example, both knowledge bases contain the value `ds:idsensore` which is a literal. So it's not clear what you want as you said that you want to join on those values.